# how to convert date in month python?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

i m currently working in Generating dynamic invoice on monthly basis but i m stuck in getting month name in python from user input date

Example: Given Date is :15/03/2020 is date and month is March

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are receiving the date in the form of a string like `"15/03/2020"`:

`int(date.split('/')[1])` returns the value between the first and second `/` of `date` as an integer.  This can then be used as the index for a list of month names to return the name of the month:

```
months = ["January","February","March",...]
print(months[int(date.split('/')[1])-1])
```